# Create a working standalone Windows executable

Tags: qgis, python, pyinstaller

Has anyone been able to create a working standalone Windows .EXE file from a QGIS Python Script Using PyInstaller?

I'm create to file.exe ..not found..## Heading ##failed to execute script...

```
File "site-packages\geopandas\base.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\osgeo4w64\apps\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\rtree\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\osgeo4w64\apps\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\rtree\index.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\osgeo4w64\apps\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\rtree\core.py", line 116, in <module>
OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll
[12116] Failed to execute script mergefiles_completo
```

Comment: Not an answer but there is this similar error/ answer over at Stack Exchange:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901732/could-not-find-or-load-spatialindex-c-dll-in-windows